# Postgresql date inconsistent format

Tags: postgresql, date, format

I am building an app using node with a Postgres backend. I have a column for date where the data type is `date`. The dates in the database are stored in the format YYYY-MM-DD. However, when I do a query in my app, the date returned is in the format YYYY-MM-DD + (time zone information). For example:

`2016-01-06T05:00:00.000Z`

Does anyone know how I can prevent this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html)

```
SELECT to_char(dateColumn, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS formattedDate FROM ...
```

Example:

```
ubuntu=> SELECT to_char(to_timestamp('2016-01-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  to_char
------------
 2016-01-07
(1 row)
```